# Setting proxy with Alamofire Session

Tags: macos, swift, proxy, alamofire

I am attempting to bind a proxy to a particular http request. So I have created a proxy class as outlined below which grabs a proxy and binds it using the kCF properties.

```
class Proxy {

     func configureProxy(proxy: String) -> NSURLSessionConfiguration {
        let proxyArr = proxy.componentsSeparatedByString(":")

        let host = proxyArr[0]
        let port = proxyArr[1].toInt()

        if let p  = port{
            return newSession(host, port: p)
        }

        return NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    }

     func newSession(host: String, port: Int) -> NSURLSessionConfiguration  {


        let proxyInfo = [
            kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyHost : host as NSString,
            kCFStreamPropertyHTTPProxyPort : port,
            kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPEnable as NSString : true
        ]

        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        config.connectionProxyDictionary = proxyInfo


        return config
    }
}
```

This is my service class which receives a request from any service class which extends it. E.G (HttpBin : Service). Once all setup is done including the correct router (which is just a mutableUrlRequest), the service class is responsible for sending the http request. For testing purposes the configuration is done during the initialization of the Service class.

```
class Service {

    var res      = ResponseHandler()
    var alamofireManager : Alamofire.Manager?


    init(){
        let ipconfig = Proxy()
        let config = ipconfig.configureProxy(VALIDPROXY)
        alamofireManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: config)
    }

    func createRequest(Router : routes, type : String, completion:(response: ResponseHandler) -> Void){

        if let manager = alamofireManager {
            println(manager.session.configuration.connectionProxyDictionary)

        switch(type){
            case "download":
                manager.request(Router).responseImage() {
                    (_, _, image, error) in

                    self.res.image   = image
                    self.res.success = true
                    completion(response: self.res)
                }
                break;
            case "upload":
                manager.upload(Router, data: uploadData)
                    .responseJSON { (request,response, JSON, error) in
                        self.res = self.getResponse(JSON, error : error)
                    }.responseString{ (_,_,string,error) in
                        if (error != nil){
                            println(error)
                        }
                        self.res.responseString = string
                        completion(response: self.res)
            }
            default:
                manager.request(Router)
                    .responseJSON { (request,response, JSON, error) in
                        self.res = self.getResponse(JSON, error : error)
                    }.responseString{ (_,_,string,error) in
                        self.res.responseString = string
                        println(error)
                        println(string)
                        completion(response: self.res)
            }
        }
        }

    }


    func getResponse(serverData : AnyObject?, error: NSError?)-> ResponseHandler{

        if let data: AnyObject = serverData {

            self.res.response = SwiftyJSON.JSON(data.0)
            if(error == nil){
                self.res.success = true
            }
            else{
                self.res.error   = error
                println(error)
            }
        }
        return self.res
    }
}
```

Upon hitting my test api, the client ip from the request appears to be my ip & not the one created from the proxyInfo dictionary. manager.session.configuration.connectionProxyDictionary prints the values set in the dictionary. Any ideas if something in the Alamofire framework prevents this or if it is my implementation that is wrong?

EDIT:

I am trying some stuff by implementing NSURLProtocol and using the CFReadStreamSetProperty functions to intercept requests before they are sent. So far no luck.

Edit1: 
:(

Comment: did you ever found a solution for this? I'm starting to think it's an NSURLSession issue. That, or we're certainly not understanding something in the docs